# How to get height of custom views?

Tags: android, view, calendar

[image]

The XML code consists of the white lines on the bottom of 8:00 and 9:00.
How do I refer to these in my draw class that extends view?

The class that uses this layout is a fragment. The draw class extends view for this fragment so that it could draw rectangles.

```
        <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width = "match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1" />
        <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width = "match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/view2" />
```

I've managed to get a day view layout for the application I'm developing right now. Is there a way to get the height for every horizontal white line that separates the times?

I need the heights so that I could draw rectangles from a start time to an end time for a particular activity/event.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the divider-line id's? `findViewById(R.id.view1)`

If yes, try `view.getHeight()` or the difference between `view.getTop()` and `view.getBottom()`